# How can I get all widget_instances of a widget type from the database?

Tags: magento2, php, widget

I created a new widget type named "lorem_widget" and also a few widgets instances of them, which are persisted in widget_instances.
Now I want to get all of these widgets out of the database to update some widget parameters.

```
public function __construct(
  ...
  \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\InstanceFactory $widgetFactory
  ) { 
    ...
    $this->widgetFactory = $widgetFactory;
  }

  public function updateAllLoremWidgets()
  {
    $widgetCollection = $this->widgetFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $widgetCollection->addFieldToFilter('instance_type', 'Lorem\Ipsum\Block\Widget\LoremWidget');

    foreach($widgetCollection->getItems() as $item) {
      $item->setData('widget_parameters', 'whatever');
      $item->save();
  }

}
```

But there are no items in $widgetCollection. But when I use the load($id)-method on the $widgetFactory, I get the corresponding widget_instance.
Does anyone know why it's not working? And does anyone have maybe a better approach to load all widgets of a certain type?

Comment: Does it work if you change the filter to 'Lorem\\Ipsum\\Block\\Widget\\LoremWidget'?

Comment: @jiheison no, unfortunately not. It is not about the filter, it is about the "getCollection()" method. It returns just an empty collection. But there are widget instances in the database (widget_instance)

Comment: The issue was solved by using an instance of the collection directly. Plus, I forgot that Magento 2 uses lazy loading. So it only gets the data from the database, when I do something with it (e. g. iterating). So of course there are no items on $widgetCollection when using ->getCollection() because Magento only establishes the connection. Still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Inject Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\InstanceFactory and Magento\Widget\Model\ResourceModel\Widget\Instance\CollectionFactory in your constructor.

   widgetInstanceFactory = $widgetInstanceFactory;
        $this->widgetInstanceCollectionFactory = $widgetInstanceCollectionFactory;
    }
2. Create a function to get widget instance by type

   widgetInstanceCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('instance_type', ['eq' => $type]);

        return $collection->getFirstItem();
    }

This will return the first widget instance matching the instance_type filter. If you want all instances, just return the collection, and then you can loop over the collection to get each individual instance.

Notice: The Magento\Widget\Model\ResourceModel\Widget\Instance\CollectionFactory class is not a physical file that you can find in the Magento core code.
Instead, it's a class that is generated by the Magento Framework at runtime.